# How to plot subplot and independent table in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Currently, I'm trying to make some chart for visualizing information with matplotlib.pyplot

I need one table and 2 subplot chart at figure
but I face 2 problems

1. I can't remove first empty space
2. I can't make table texts bigger

here is my code and execution result plz help me
thank you

```py
fig  = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)

# answer table
ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[:, 0])
ax0.table(
    cellText=dummy_data, 
    colLabels=col_labels,
    rowLabels=np.arange(1,31),
    loc='left',
    cellColours=cell_colors,
    bbox=[left, bottom, width, height],
)
# graph that contain timeseires scores
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax1.plot([1,2,3])

# graph that indicate weak point
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 1])
ax2.plot([1,2,3])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLWOn.png)